# android OneSignal import Error

Tags: android, build.gradle, onesignal

hi i'm trying to use [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com) in android and i'm following this tutorial to install the SDK in Android Studio. [here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-setup)

i was able to compile the dependencies and sync the gradle file. but when i want to import `com.onesignal.OneSignal;` it says: Cannot resolve symbol!

here is my dependencies in app.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:1.10.+@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+'
    compile project(':gson-2.2.2')
    compile project(':java_websocket')
    compile project(':signalr-client-sdk')
    compile project(':signalr-client-sdk-android')
}
```

thing i done:

```
1. File > Synchronize
2. File > Invalidate Cashes and Restart
```

UPDATE:

i did the steps in a new project and that was ok!
why i can't do it in this specific project?

EDIT:

whole build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ir.irsapardaz.sina.gamev01"
        manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId:"${applicationId}"]
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:1.10.+@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+'
    compile project(':gson-2.2.2')
    compile project(':java_websocket')
    compile project(':signalr-client-sdk')
    compile project(':signalr-client-sdk-android')
}
```

Comment: Its importing, I tried.

Comment: i don't know what's wrong with android studio! i have no idea what to do. i't integrating to a new project!

Comment: Just now I tried with android studio, it works fine.

Comment: Can you post your whole build.gradle?

Comment: Everything looks fine, I also tried its working on my case.

Comment: Once clean the project and check

Comment: @NigamPatro restarted windows and fixed :) thanks for your replies

Answer (score 10):

Use the following in your gradle file to get the latest OneSignal SDK 3.X version.

```
compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.8.3, 3.99.99]'
```

The error you're are seeing is normally due to Android Studio either not pulling in the SDK from Maven Central or you haven't synced your `.gradle` since you added OneSignal to it.

In your case going to `Tool` > `Android` > `Sync Project` should fix the following error

```
com.onesignal.OneSignal; Cannot resolve symbol!
```

See OneSignal's documentation for a few more things to try if that doesn't work.
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/troubleshooting-android

Answer (score 1):

if anyone comes across this for ReactNative v0.37, i had a similar issue, but my code was newer in general. the following solved it:

for android be sure to use:

`import com.geektime.reactnativeonesignal.ReactNativeOneSignalPackage;` and NOT `import com.geektime.rnonesignal.ReactNativeOneSignalPackage;`

some old documentation had the rnonesignal and that's since been updated.

YMMV if you are using something lower than v0.37 of RN. good luck.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Click here for image reference]

[image: Click here for image reference]

In your Build gradel file

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {

        applicationId "ir.irsapardaz.sina.gamev01"
        manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId:"${applicationId}"]
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Under

```
default Config{

}
```

add this :

```
manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: " Your app ID as provided by OneSignal ",

onesignal_google_project_number: " Your Sender Id as provided by Google firebase "
```

Answer (score 0):

compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:2.3.0' Try this in gradle file.Version will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

In your build.gradle add this dependencies and sync gradle file I hope it will works.

```
 compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.+@aar'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1'
 compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'
```

You can also see the proper OneSignal's documentation if that doesn't work.
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-setup